# Obtaining the decryption keys for Super Mario Run (Android/iOS Game)

Tags: ida, encryption, decryption

Super Mario Run is a *il2cpp* Unity game. Most of its assets are downloaded in-game through http requests. I particularly want the OGG files of the music. I can see the list of their names comes from this [file](https://download-cdn-supermariorun.akamaized.net/native/e07e1191b490a31c/3.0.1/raw/RawSound/DeALProject.json).

I know this because it appears before all the requests of the OGGs are made, sadly it and the OGGs are [encrypted](https://download-cdn-supermariorun.akamaized.net/native/e07e1191b490a31c/3.0.1/raw/RawSound/sound/BGM/Athletic_RB_32.ogg).

Since Super Mario Run is an *il2cpp* game, the strings and function names and whatnot are contained in a different file -- "*global-metadata.dat*". Looking at this file I can see a function named `get_OggEncryptionAesKey`, as for where this function is and what it returns I cannot find out.

I disassembled the "*libil2cpp.so*" with IDA, but did not seem to find this function or anything useful.

I believe that the libraries that deal with the encryption might be "*libdeal.so*" or "*libDeALWrapper.so*".

Closest I've came was pulling the ogg's from memory, but the best I got was some interface sounds.

Does anyone have any other ideas to decrypt these files?

Comment: If you obtain the encrypted files through http requests on runtime I can imagine the related decryption is also send somewhere during this process. Did you try to sniff the network requests/responses?

Comment: I checked them all and didn't find anything that looked like an encryption key.

Comment: I believe `libdeal` is just a library for dealing with algorithms and complex data structures in C++ (not sure though). Atleast we know they use `AES` encryption. Maybe you can try to find the `Rijndael` algorithm and work from there?

Comment: Also, have you looked at https://github.com/nevermoe/unity_metadata_loader ?

Comment: @JevgeniGeurtsen I used that, but none of the files I've decompiled had the OggEncryptionAesKey function although they had all the other functions from the same class, very strange.

Comment: So you didn't find any functions related to encrypting/decrypting inside the decompiled files? You shouldn't look for the `OggEncryptionAesKey` property but rather to the encrypting/decrypt function itself and find out where its being called (so you can find the key there).